# iterate over objects/list

Tags: java, json, spring, list

I wrote all classes to make better sense out of what i am trying to achieve.
i am having issue with looping or if there is some other option.. what i am confused is currently i have my index set at 0. how do i loop through list and perform function

```
if(empgrouping = group-A){use group-A position and ID} 
else
if(empgrouping = group-B){use group-B position and ID}
```

---

```
private Employeesset employeesset (String personal, String empgrouping) throws Exception{
    Employeesset emp = new Employeesset();

    Details details = employeeconfig.getempdepts().get(0);

    if(emp.flagistrue()&&empgrouping.equals(“group-A”){
           emp.setemplgroup(empgrouping);
           emp.setposition(“”);
           emp.setidentification(“”);
    }else{
  // choose group b or c//
```

—————————————————

```
“employee_details”:[
{“Employees  “: ”group-A“,
“Position  “: ”management“,
“ID “: ”333iisdsa“,
“Environments” :
 [  
    "name":"Shyam",   
    "name":"Bob", 
    "name":"Jai"
]} ,
{"Employees  “: ”group-B”,
“Position  “: ”management“,
“ID “: ”4455iisdf“,
“Environments” :
[  
      "name”:”sam”, 
    "name”:”loki”,  
    "name”:”avenger” 
]},
{"Employees  “: ”group-c“,
“Position  “: ”management“,
“ID “: ”234kkdk“,
“Environments” : [  
    "name”:”super”, 
    "name”:”kam”,  
    "name”:”mike”
]}    
]
```

———————————————

```
public static class Details{
@Jsonproperty(“Employees”)
String emptype;

@Jsonproperty(“Position”)
String position;

@Jsonproperty(“ID”)
String identification;

@Jsonproperty(“environments”)
List<Environments> environments;

//Getters and setters//
```

———————————

```
public class employeeconfig{
@Jsonproperty(“employee_details”);
List<Details> empdepts;

//getters and setters//
```

—————————————

```
public class Employeesset{
private employee;
private position;
private identification;

//getters and setters//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change the whole structure of code for Class you have written `Employeesset` which should be `EmployeesSet` Then method should always follow camel casing structure same with variables

```
private EmployeesSet employeesSet (String personal, String empGrouping) throws Exception{
    EmployeesSet emp = new EmployeesSet();

     employeeConfig.getempdepts().foreach(resultDetails->{

//Write your code logic here                                //Using jdk 8
}

    if(emp.flagistrue()&&empGrouping.equals(“group-A”){
           emp.setemplgroup(empGrouping);
           emp.setposition(“”);
           emp.setidentification(“”);
    }else{
```